# virtualenv issues on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to setup a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper on my Ubuntu 16.04 development machine for python3.5.x. I installed them with the following:

```
sudo -H python3 get-pip.py
sudo -H pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Here's the state of things:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
$ md5sum `which pip`
b1d4013513817094e7cf0779f0963c87  /usr/local/bin/pip
$ md5sum `which pip3`
b1d4013513817094e7cf0779f0963c87  /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

and my ~/.bash_profile has the following in it:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.venvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

but when I go to run things, I get the following:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ mkvirtualenv just_testing
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/get_env_details
/home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
$ pip install numpy 
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.0
(just_testing) $ which python
/home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python
(just_testing) $ python
>>> import numpy as np  # works fine!?
>>> exit()
(just_testing) $ deactivate
/home/me/.venvs/just_testing/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
$
```

I keep getting this same `Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')` error, however my virtualenv seems to be functional.

Any ideas what's happening here?